# How to fix error -245 while updating row in informix

Tags: sql-update, informix

-245 Could not position within a file via an index.

I got this error when I want to update one row in a table.
There are 8 indexes on this table and the table has about 30000 rows.

Here is the full description for this error

> The database server encountered an error when it attempted to look up
>   a row through an index. Check the accompanying ISAM error code for
>   more information. The table file or the index file might have been
>   corrupted. Unless the ISAM error code or an operating-system message
>   points to another cause, run the oncheck utility (secheck with IBM
>   Informix SE or tbcheck with IBM Informix OnLine) to check and repair
>   table and index.

Comment: What is the UPDATE statement condition?  Does it allow the optimizer to use an index to find the row to be updated (`WHERE pk_column = value`, for example) or does it have to read many columns?  What else is going on concurrently?  Which version of Informix, and on which platform?  What is the ISAM error (that should be a number between 100 and 199).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need to the ISAM error to answer this question properly.

Usually this is due to locking, review application locking strategy and isolation levels and well as access plans for DML.